# Reg Expression javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate a string to have only letters, digits up to 4, '.', and '_';

Right now I am using

```
if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$/.test(testString)) 
{
     console.log("Valid string");
}

testString = test.com // (must be valid) 
testString = Te_St.com // (must be valid) 
testString = Te_St1.com // (must be valid) 
testString = Te_St12.com // (must be invalid because has 12 in it and is higher than 4) 
testString = Te_2St1.com // (must be valid) 
testString = Te_24St1.com // (must be invalid because has 24 in it and it higher than 4) 
testString = Te_2$St1.com // (must be invalid because has ilegal character $)
```

Comment: Can you also post the reasons why some inputs are invalid

Comment: Is `test01.com` valid or invalid? (or is it irrelevant?)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the pattern below:

```
/^[a-z._]*(?:[01234](?:[a-z._]+|$))*$/i
```

but note that this pattern succeeds with an empty string. To prevent this, you can test the string length before or add a lookahead at the start of the pattern:

```
/^(?=.)[a-z._]*(?:[01234](?:[a-z._]+|$))*$/i
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!.*[1-9]\d)[a-zA-Z0-4_.]+$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/12